# how to detect document size change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, resize, size

so suppose that clicking something would lead to a new content being loaded to the screen hence the height of document changes and whereas previously there are no scroll bars, now there actually are scrollbars...

how do I detect something like that happening using jquery

binding resize event onto window only detects window resize whereas binding it into document doesn't work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:**
Please don't use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event. It is old, deprecated and not well-supported by browsers. In 99,9 % of the cases, there is a different event you can listen on. Most likely you are one of those people using jQuery and doing some AJAX stuff, so please take a look at their [AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

---

[These](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) are all available events. You would have to detect `$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() { ... });` and check for a dimension change to the previous firing.

```
var height = $(this).height(),
    width  = $(this).width();
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if($(this).height() != height || $(this).width() != width) {
        recalibrate();
    }
});
```

This event is firing **every** time **anything** is done to the DOM. Therefore it **will** slowdown your browser.

We should get a better alternative. Could you please give us more information to your scenario?

Comment: You may change `$(document)` to `$("body")` or something similar.

Comment: well basically, there is a button and when a user click on that button jquery fires the load() function which loads another content from another url using ajax and replace an empty div with that content...

Comment: also I can't be putting some function in the load()'s call back since when I do so, the function fires before the entire loaded content even displays on screen hence before the size change actually occurs

Comment: Then just do the check, when your content is loaded. That means, that you have to include the check in the callback function of `.load()`.

Comment: yeah but the timeout would be unreliable since the time it takes to load is variable so if the timeout is not long enough it may fail yet if it's too long, it may end up being useless...besides how long is long enough

Comment: Sorry, but the callback won't fire until the content is loaded. That's the sense on a callback function. See here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I think DOMSubtreeModified isn't supported anymore.

Comment: This solution is not cross-browser.

Comment: Added a deprecation notice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
// ajdust margins when page size changes (ie rotate mobile device)
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Do something more useful
  console.log('doc height is ' + $(window).height());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try a percentage scrolled event like this one:
http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-detect-scrolled-page/

You might need to add a check to see whether the vertical scrollbar is present:

```
var hasVScroll = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
```