# Can you bind .resize() to $(document) instead of $(window)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if `$(document).resize()` should make sense or not?

The problem is that when the document gets larger (i.e. a `div` get extended for some reason) the height of the document changes. I would like to stretch my background image so that the added area to the document won't be blank. What would be the best way of doing this?

Basically, is there a way to get notified when the document height has changed?

To be clear, I don't want my image to repeat.

Comment: I did and it seems not to work. But, I'd imagine that it should, hence the question. I'm also looking for an alternative way that would do what I need done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url(yourImage.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) is [supported by all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility).

The `cover` property will cause the image to be as small as possible but still cover the element completely. It maintains aspect ratio and will crop if necessary.

Comment: This is a great way to do it, but you lose support for almost every version of IE (which are unfortunately still popular). Still, +1 because I didn't know about "cover".

Comment: There is no perfect solution. I would use CSS when possible (for performance reasons) and a polyfill for older browsers. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect if background-size is supported, [jQuery plugin like this one](http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image) when it isn't. @Roozbeh15, you could look at the source of that plugin to see how it's done.

Comment: Agreed, CSS is always the best solution. I nearly forgot about Modernizr, which is amazingly useful in cases like this. Nice suggestion.

Comment: I do use cover, but it doesn't fix the problem of document getting resized. Cover is great though, definitely very useful.

Comment: CSS modifications don't get 'stale'. i.e. if the element is set to `background-size: cover;`, the background will *always* cover that element. If you're using it, that indicates that the element it's applied to isn't actually changing sizes. Look at your page under Firebug or Webkit Inspector to make sure that child nodes are being fully contained by their parents. Applying `overflow: hidden;` to those parents will stop this problem.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but the problem is that the height of <body> doesn't change when the height of the document changes. If it did then your cover solution would be golden and I wouldn't have this problem to begin with! :)

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is that you can fix that. If `body` shorter than `document` then there is a problem. One or more of your `divs` are not being properly contained by their parents. It can be fixed with `overflow: hidden;`. Do you have a live site I can look at?

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean!!! Sorry the site isn't live yet... So, back to my original problem of divs not being properly contained by their parents... I'm going to accept your solution. I'd appreciate if you could tell me how I can properly have my divs contained. I don't want to hide the overflow btw, I'd like to make the parent divs expand

Comment: Thanks, use Firebug or Webkit inspector to view your page. When you mouseover elements in the code window, it will highlight them on the page. Start at `body` and move down the tree mousing over each element. When you get to an element whose highlight box is smaller than you think it should be (often, height of 0), apply the CSS: 'overflow: hidden;' to it. This will force that element to contain it's children. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, what if I want to expand the parent div instead of clipping it off? Is there an easy way of doing that? I don't understand why my parent div does not expand with the child div... apparently it is not contained properly as you mentioned.

Comment: If it's clipping when you apply `overflow: hidden;` then that element has an absolute height. Make it `height: auto;` to expand with it's children. If you need it to be at least a certain height, use `min-height: 100px;`

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, `$(document).resize()` will detect changes in the document size.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard `document.resize` event that you can hook into.

A common technique is to check when the DOM tree is modified, thus likely to change document height and then adjust anything that you'd like to adjust in there: [how to detect document size change in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532453/how-to-detect-document-size-change-in-jquery). Be warned that it may not be a good thing to do performance-wise.

Firefox exposes an event [Detecting document width and height changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Detecting_document_width_and_height_changes), but then, its FF only.

Your best bet is to use a cover image that kind of tapers off and use the end color as background color for the document. It can give you this effect where it seems the image continues but without using the image. A good example of this is [twitter](https://twitter.com/).

Comment: Hah... yeah keeping track of the modifications in the DOM tree is definitely not practical for my project.

How would the background color help btw? The problem is that the size of body doesn't update when the document size changes. So, I don't know how having a background color would be different from using the cover property mentioned above.

Comment: I haven't used the `cover` property, so can't say for that. The `background-color` thing works on Twitter where it dynamically adds new tweets as you scroll down and down.

Answer (score 0):

Try **DOMSubtreeModified** event:

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    ...
});
```